# Gratis iOS application that shows the battery charging speed

Tags: gratis, ios, monitoring, battery

I'm looking a gratis iOS application that can show the current battery charging speed.

On Android I use  [Accu​Battery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.accubattery&hl=en_US&gl=US):

[image]

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.